# Using GoTo in a Visual Basic Forms Application

Tags: winforms

I am struggling to figure out how to use GoTo in a VB Windows Form Application. I've tried putting it in a Public Sub, inside the Public Class and outside but they all seem to flag up the error "Not defined" or "Can't be used outside a method"?

```
WinDetection: MessageBox.Show("You won congrats!", "Congrats!")

Private Sub TL_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TL.TextChanged
   If TL.Text = "Won" Then
   GoTo WinDetection
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where would the code continue after it has shown the message? Using `GoTo` leads to code that is hard to read/predict, instead you could put the message-code in a sub and call that.

Comment: Unless used in specific cases of error handling, `GOTO` is a sign of bad code structure. Instead of figuring out how to use it, see how you can avoid it.

Comment: GoTo can only go to a label that is defined in the same method.  Rockhard restriction.  Maybe you like Return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You musn't use GOTO in programming. Because its not a good way to turn back. Programs are compiling top to bottom and if you use GOTO, program compiles be wrong. You can use method with parameter or without parameter and you can call it easly or you can use loops. I don't advise use GOTO. In future you'll stuck i guess.